# ¿Como descargo mi web mediante javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo

```
<a onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#" download="miweb.html">Descarga</a>
```

que me descarga mi web si hago click en el  pero yo quiero que se descargue automaticamente cuando termina de cargar la página.
Sería algo como

```
window.addEventListener("load",descargarweb)
```

y que la funcion *descargarweb* me haga lo que me hace mi botón.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tendrías que hacer un scrap con AJAX

Comment: podrias definir que es descargar tu web? que es lo que queres descargar?